# scipy.ndimage.generic_filter returns Type Error

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, ndimage

I am using the `scipy.ndimage.generic_filter` to calculate localised modal values of an array.  I was comparing two methods to see which is faster (as the first approach is quite slow). My first approach is;

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import scipy.ndimage

def modal(arr):
    return stats.mode(arr, axis=None)[0][0]

x = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(10, 10))
scipy.ndimage.filters.generic_filter(x, modal, size=3)
```

My second approach is;

```
def modal(arr):
    return np.argmax(np.bincount(arr.flatten()))

x = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(10, 10))
scipy.ndimage.filters.generic_filter(x, modal, size=3)
```

But with the second approach I get this:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-122-2e9030c57d71> in <module>()
      1 #%timeit -n 5 -r 1
----> 2 scipy.ndimage.filters.generic_filter(x, modal, size=3)

C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\scipy\ndimage\filters.pyc in generic_filter(input, function, size, footprint, output, mode, cval, origin, extra_arguments, extra_keywords)
   1161     mode = _ni_support._extend_mode_to_code(mode)
   1162     _nd_image.generic_filter(input, function, footprint, output, mode,
-> 1163                          cval, origins, extra_arguments, extra_keywords)
   1164     return return_value

<ipython-input-118-86ea9b03ed30> in modal(arr)
      1 def modal(arr):
----> 2     return np.argmax(np.bincount(arr.flatten()))
      3     return stats.mode(arr, axis=None)[0][0]

TypeError: array cannot be safely cast to required type
```

When I run this:

```
stats.mode(x, axis=None)[0][0] == np.argmax(np.bincount(x.flatten()))
```

It returns `True`

Why does the `generic_filter` throw the type error when using the `numpy.bincount` method and not the `stats.mode` method when the returned value is the same?

I am using Python 2.7.3, Numpy 1.6.1 and Scipy 0.14.0 on Windows 7 (I am stuck to this version of Numpy and Python as this is what ships with ESRI ArcGIS). I tried installing scikit-image to calculate the modal filter but I got other errors on install and thought it simpler to resolve this one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can investigate this error by putting a print statement in `modal`:

```
def modal(arr):
    print(arr)
    return np.argmax(np.bincount(arr.flatten()))
```

You'll see output like

```
[ 92.  92.  31.  92.  92.  31.  87.  87.  18.]
```

which shows that `arr` contains floats, not ints. The documentation for `np.bincount` states its first argument must be a 1 dimensional array of *nonnegative ints*.

So, you can avoid the error by using `astype('int64')` to cast the floats as ints.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import scipy.ndimage

def modal(arr):
    return stats.mode(arr, axis=None)[0][0]

def modal2(arr):
    count = np.bincount(arr.astype('int64'))
    return np.argmax(count)

x = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(10, 10))

out = np.empty_like(x, dtype='float')
scipy.ndimage.filters.generic_filter(x, modal, size=3, output=out)
print(out)

scipy.ndimage.filters.generic_filter(x, modal2, size=3, output=out)
print(out)
```

PS. The call to `flatten` can be removed since `arr` is already one dimensional.